# Running JavaScript function before page load (setting background of appropriate size)

Tags: javascript, background, load

I've got an image background which content I want to be always visible, no matter what is the user's resolution. Therefore, I want to be able to determine what is the resolution and set appropriate background image file before page loads, on the very beginning. Is it possible somehow?

Comment: +1 for the idea and asking the question.

Comment: What if the user resizes their window?

Comment: Nothing. The background should fit to screen's resolution, not to current size of the window.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The earliest point at which you can run a Javascript function with access to the DOM (without waiting for page load) is by placing a `<script>` tag right after the opening `<body>` tag.

***Scripts inside the `<head>` will run before this occurs, but there won't be access to the elements on the page.***

Try this code

```
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        alert("Some elements shouldn't even be visible when this shows");
    </script>
    ... rest of the page
</body>
```

See this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/marko/CvWT3/) with some **Gangsta Lipsum** text.

Comment: Really? So when does the scripts in the head execute?

Comment: @some: Good question. It runs BEFORE the `<body>` tag, but there is no access to the elements on the page. I should clarify that.

Comment: You only have access to the elements that has been declared before the script-tag because the rest of the page hasn't been parsed yet. That's the reason why people waits for the DOM to be loaded before they start to touch it. A decent framework makes it very easy to attach a function to the DOM-loaded event in a cross browser way.

Comment: Yes @some, but placing something right after the `<body>` will mean you have access to **JUST** the `<body>` which is what the OP wants. Given a large page, there will be a significant delay before the new background image is shown.

Comment: You also have access to `<html>` and `<head>` if they are specified... Sorry :) OP could put in a style sheet in the header, with javascript: `<script type="text/javascript">document.write("<style type='text/css'>body{background:#f00;}<\/style>");</script>` (could calculate width and height and put `url(image" +dim ")` with the color.)

Answer (score 1):

Check this article on getting screen resolution in Javascript: http://andylangton.co.uk/articles/javascript/browser-screen-resolution/

Script tags execute inline if you don't do anything special to defer them (and deferring script execution is not supported on all browsers). This means a script tag nested just inside the body tag will be executed before the rest of the body loads. You could have your script detect the screen resolution and set the background image for the body right there.

Comment: I know how to get screen's resolution, thanks :). I would love to accept both of your answers but since it's not possible and @Marko's answer is more complex I have to take a decision. But thanks again and have a point for useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using a JavaScript framework like [MooTools](http://mootools.net/) you can utilize the [DomReady](http://demos111.mootools.net/DomReadyVS.Load) event instead of onLoad (which waits for all image elements to load) you can fire an event when the page has loaded.

Alternatively with CSS you can position absolute top left and width:100% to win the day. :O

Comment: I prefer not to use external code if I can do it easily without it :). As for the second part of your answer - I don't want it to resize with the window, but to adjust to screen's width. But thanks anyway :).

Answer (score 0):

I realize you're specifically asking about JavaScript, but there's a pretty [decent technique for doing this with CSS](http://css-tricks.com/how-to-resizeable-background-image/) (and optionally a little JavaScript) described at the CSS Tricks site.

Comment: I don't want it to resize with the window, but to adjust to screen's width. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: The technique I linked to uses CSS to scale the image so that it fits the browser viewport. It does not resize the window.

Comment: I know - "I don't want it to resize with the window" - it means: "I don't want to scale the background when the window (and the browser's viewport) changes its size". I want to adjust it only to screen's width.