# PHP File Tree displays tree expanded first then collapse and causes flickering on initial page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been using this [PHP File Tree](https://www.abeautifulsite.net/php-file-tree) library with jQuery for quite some time now.  Although it works flawlessly for my requirements (thanks to the author for sharing), one little detail bothers me.  When loading/refreshing the web page, the file tree always shows up fully expanded first then very quickly gets collapsed by the following function call:

> $(".php-file-tree").find("UL").hide();

Is there a way to either call this function before the page content gets displayed to the users or perhaps temporarily hide displaying anything on the page until this function did it's magic?

The whole idea is that the user would not see the initial expanded tree, only the collapsed view.

jQuery version used : 3.1.1

Answer (score 0):

Maybe adding script after `<body>` tag can help you.

Check more info here:

- [Running JavaScript function before page load (setting background of appropriate size)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4000654/running-javascript-function-before-page-load-setting-background-of-appropriate)

Comment: Doesn't change anything